# Very weird behavior showing a Youtube video on iPad

Tags: ios, webview, youtube

I have an array of youtube video links, and I put them in a tableview. When the user clicks on one row a WebView is pushed in, and I point it to the video URL like this

```
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQXIuYVNM9Q"]]];
```

this was working perfectly 'till yesterday, and the result was

[image]

but since today the behavior is different! What happens is that the firs time I click on a row, the video is displayed as always. But then if I go back and click on the same video again, it doesn't appear anymore, and istead I get the following screen

[image]

This is very weird! If I choose an other video from the list the first time it loads, then from the second time it doesn't and I get the same useless screen with the video thumbnails.
Even if I uninstall the app and start it again, the video that were already clicked don't work, while the others work just once. It looks like it's a cache problem or something similar...

Please help me, this is driving me mad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a weird workaround using arc4number:

```
NSString *s = @"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLl92XBsYmc&feature=youtube_gdata"

s = [s stringByAppendingFormat:@"%f", arc4random()];

[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:s]]];
```

so every time the address is different, and the video gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use the embedded link from youtube as this may solve this issue.

Comment: Youtube provides you with an embed link for all videos. Use that

Comment: You mean the embedded player? Then the result would be different, because you cannot add a comment or rate the video